# Jquery .css("background-image") does nothing

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the background image of a div with Jquery and its not working

here is the html and jquery

```
<div class = "displayUser" id = "cover">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.displayUser').css("background-image", "url(../images/group_icon.png) no-repeat;");
});


</script>

</div>
```

here is my css

```
.displayUser{
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

}
```

Why isnt it working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to split css rules, removing `no-repeat;` from jQuery code, then it works well.

To do this, you must write two css rules and you can do it using an object as argument.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.displayUser').css({
    'background-image': "url(../images/group_icon.png)',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

two things:

```
<div class="displayUser" id="cover">
```

and:

```
$('.displayUser').css("background-image", "url('../images/group_icon.png')");
```

1. remove the whitespaces before/after `id` and `class` attributes.
2. and remove the `no-repeat;` from the script and put single quotes in `url('')`.

Answer (score 0):

your url needs to be quoted
like this

```
url('../images/group_icon.png')
```